# C# problem with string received on tcpclient socket

Tags: c#, string, sockets, tcpclient

I have tcp client C# code. It works fine for connecting to any port and getting data. It works with linux/unix servers fine too. But in one case, when I connect to a linux server (openwrt), I can receive data but I can't show the string. The code shows that string contains what I want, but `MessageBox.Show` doesn't show the string.

What's the problem?

```
string ip = "192.168.0.1";
string command ="MT15";
string result = "None";

int i = 0;
int bytesRead;

byte[] rec_message = new byte[65535];

StringBuilder Whole_Message = new StringBuilder();
int port = 8889;

var client = new TcpClient();

NetworkStream ns;
int total = 0;

if (!client.ConnectAsync(ip, port).Wait(1000)) 
{ 
     result = "Failed"; 
}

byte[] byteTime = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
ns = client.GetStream();
ns.Write(byteTime, 0, byteTime.Length);

// the string.contain Shows the string contains the mac address
while (!result.Contains("C2:04:28:00:5F:F1"))
{
    bytesRead = ns.Read(rec_message, 0, rec_message.Length);
    total = total + bytesRead;

    result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rec_message, 0, total);
    Whole_Message.AppendFormat("{0}", result);

    //row = Whole_Message.ToString().Split(',');
}

string r = Whole_Message.ToString();
// the string.contain returns true, so the string contains the mac address

if (r.Contains("C2:04:28:00:5F:F1"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(r);
}

client.Close();
```

But the MessageBox only shows "MT15"

The tcpdump packet sniff result :

```
18:06:21.430073 IP 192.168.0.2.6481 > 192.168.0.1.8889: tcp 4
E..,HX....cg%...%....Q".....5#v.P.@t....MT15..

18:06:21.439163 IP 192.168.0.1.8889 > 192.168.0.2.6481: tcp 0
E..(*.@.=..,%...%..."..Q5#v.....P....|..

18:06:21.475525 IP 192.168.0.1.8889 > 192.168.0.2.6481: tcp 23
E..?*.@.=...%...%..."..Q5#v.....P.......MT15..C2:04:28:00:5F:F1
```

The message is "MT15..C2:04:28:00:5F:F1" but the messagebox shows only "MT15"
this not an issue with messagebox, I can't store and read to datatable or debug.write.

Comment: i don't have access to server code, it a binary

Comment: first thought: `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rec_message, 0, total)` looks very wrong - that should be `bytesRead` surely? and `Whole_Message.AppendFormat("{0}", result);`? just `Append(result)` ?

Comment: total is amount of bytesRead. changing it makes no difference. it works with other messages from server. the whole message makes no difference too. the string contains the mac address but cant show.

Comment: um, yes, it does make a **very** big difference; it might not be your most immediate bug, but yes: that is absolutely, 100% without doubt: very wrong

Comment: *in hex*, what are the payloads you are receiving here? is there any chance you're getting something like a zero byte? many string processing APIs **stop** when they hit a zero character (`\0`), because it is considered to be a C-style null-terminated string

Comment: yeah it may have a null terminator

Comment: there you go then; check for that, and if correct: fix that

Comment: do you know how?

Comment: sec, I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *sounds* like your data has some null-characters in it, which *some* APIs (and especially: core Windows APIs like `MessageBox`) will treat as a C-style terminated string. Confusingly, *not all APIs* will do that - especially in managed code, where strings aren't expected to be null-terminated.

As an example:

```cs
MessageBox.Show("hello\0world");
```

only shows `hello` in the message box:

[image]

When seeing null characters, a fundamental question should probably be asked, i.e. *is this data really textual at all*; if you're happy that it is, then you can probably just strip them:

```
string s = ... // might contain null characters
s = s.Replace("\0",""); // now it doesn't
```